# How to extract first item in this json list

Tags: python, json

I have this json that im trying to extract the first element/list in this list of lists in python...  How do you extract the first item in ads_list?

Are there any built in functions i can use to extract first item in a json file?  I need something other than simply iterating through this like an array....

P.S. i shortened the json data

Here is the list.

```
{  
   u'data':{  
      u'ad_list':[  
         {  
            u'data':{  
               u'require_feedback_score':0,
               u'hidden_by_opening_hours':False,
               u'trusted_required':False,
               u'currency':u'EGP',
               u'require_identification':False,
               u'is_local_office':False,
               u'first_time_limit_btc':None,
               u'city':u'',
               u'location_string':u'Egypt',
               u'countrycode':u'EG',
               u'max_amount':u'20000',
               u'lon':0.0,
               u'sms_verification_required':False,
               u'require_trade_volume':0.0,
               u'online_provider':u'SPECIFIC_BANK',
               u'max_amount_available':u'20000',
               u'msg':               u" \u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605 \u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 \u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\r\n\r\n\u0625\u0630\u0627 \u0643\u0646\u062a \u062a\u0631\u063a\u0628 \u0641\u064a \u0628\u064a\u0639 \u0627\u0648 \u0634\u0631\u0627\u0621 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u062a\u0643\u0648\u064a\u0646 \u062a\u0648\u0627\u0635\u0644 \u0645\u0639\u064a \u0648\u0633\u0623\u0642\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u062e\u062f\u0645\u062a\u0643\r\n\u0644\u0644\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0635\u0644:               https:               //tawk.to/hanyibrahim\r\n  \u0627\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0627\u0631 \u0644\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644:               \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062c\u0627\u0631\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0648\u0644\u064a \u0627\u0648\u0641\u0648\u062f\u0627\u0641\u0648\u0646 \u0643\u0627\u0634 \u0627\u0648 \u0627\u062a\u0635\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0641\u0644\u0648\u0633 \u0627\u0648 \u0627\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0646\u062c \u0645\u0648\u0646\u064a\r\n\r\n'' \u0634\u0643\u0631\u0627 ''\r\n\r\n\r\n \u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605 Hello \u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\r\n\r\nIf you would like to trade Bitcoins please let me know and I will help you\r\nconnect:               https:               //tawk.to/hanyibrahim\r\nOption transfer:Bank CIB Or Vodafone Cash Or Etisalat Flous Or Orange Money\r\n'' Thank ''",
               u'volume_coefficient_btc':u'1.50',
               u'profile':{  
                  u'username':u'hanyibrahim11',
                  u'feedback_score':100,
                  u'trade_count':u'3000+',
                  u'name':u'hanyibrahim11 (3000+; 100%)',
                  u'last_online':                  u'2019-01-14T17:54:52+00:00                  '}, u'                  bank_name':u'CIB_Vodafone Cash_Etisalat Flous_Orange Money',
                  u'trade_type':u'ONLINE_BUY',
                  u'ad_id':803036,
                  u'temp_price':u'67079.44',
                  u'payment_window_minutes':90,
                  u'min_amount':u'50',
                  u'limit_to_fiat_amounts':u'',
                  u'require_trusted_by_advertiser':False,
                  u'temp_price_usd':u'3738.54',
                  u'lat':0.0,
                  u'visible':True,
                  u'created_at':                  u'2018-07-25T08:12:21+00:00                  ', u'                  atm_model':None,
                  u'is_low_risk':True
               },
               u'actions':{  
                  u'public_view':                  u'https://localbitcoins.com/ad/803036'
               }
            },
            {  
               u'data':{  
                  u'require_feedback_score':0,
                  u'hidden_by_opening_hours':False,
                  u'trusted_required':False,
                  u'currency':u'EGP',
                  u'require_identification':False,
                  u'is_local_office':False,
                  u'first_time_limit_btc':None,
                  u'city':u'',
                  u'location_string':u'Egypt',
                  u'countrycode':u'EG',
                  u'max_amount':u'20000',
                  u'lon':0.0,
                  u'sms_verification_required':False,
                  u'require_trade_volume':0.0,
                  u'online_provider':u'CASH_DEPOSIT',
                  u'max_amount_available':u'20000',
                  u'msg':u'QNB,
                  CIB deposite- Vodafone Cash - Etisalat Felous - Orange Money - Western Union - Money Gram \r\n- Please do not entiate a new trade request if you are not serious to finalize it.',
                  u'volume_coefficient_btc':u'1.50',
                  u'profile':{  
                     u'username':u'Haboush',
                     u'feedback_score':99,
                     u'trade_count':u'500+',
                     u'name':u'Haboush (500+; 99%)',
                     u'last_online':                     u'2019-01-14T16:48:52+00:00                     '}, u'                     bank_name':u'QNB\u2714CIB\u2714Vodafone\u2714Orange\u2714Etisalat\u2714WU',
                     u'trade_type':u'ONLINE_BUY',
                     u'ad_id':719807,
                     u'temp_price':u'66860.18',
                     u'payment_window_minutes':270,
                     u'min_amount':u'100',
                     u'limit_to_fiat_amounts':u'',
                     u'require_trusted_by_advertiser':False,
                     u'temp_price_usd':u'3726.32',
                     u'lat':0.0,
                     u'visible':True,
                     u'created_at':                     u'2018-03-24T19:29:08+00:00                     ', u'                     atm_model':None,
                     u'is_low_risk':True
                  },
                  u'actions':{  
                     u'public_view':                     u'https://localbitcoins.com/ad/719807'
                  }
               },

                                                            }
                                                         ],
                                                         u'ad_count':17
                                                      }
                                                   }
```

Comment: 1. this isn't valid JSON, it looks like a python2 representation of what could be parsed JSON. 2. if you properly parsed the JSON there is no reason you shouldn't be able to just get the first element by index. What have you tried, what error did you receive or how did the result vary from what you expected?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data structure is stored in the variable `j`, you can use `j['data']['ad_list'][0]` to extract the first item from the `ad_list` key. Use a `try-except` block to catch a possible `IndexError` exception if `ad_list` can ever be empty.

Comment: thanks, i tried this and it worked.  i dont know why i couldnt get it to work before,  i was doing j['data']['data']['ad_list']